# Getting JavaScript data calculated from an HTML form, and adding it to the same form action as a new element to save with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is the form:

```
<form role="form" action="<?php echo $action; ?>" name="send_request" method="post" onsubmit="calcDist();" id="send_request">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" id="input-from" class="form-control" name="from" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_from; ?>" />
      <input type="text" id="input-to" class="form-control" name="to" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_to; ?>" />
      <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="kmdist" value="">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $button_send; ?>" class="btn btn-default" />
  </div>
</form>
```

I'm computing the distance in `calcDist();` between the given cities from the text inputs on submit and save the cities to the database through the form action, but I don't know how to add that distance variable to the post data array before the actual saving action.

Comment: Do not use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` when not uploading files.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the value of the hidden field `kmdist` in `calcDist()`:

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="kmdist" id="kmdist" value="">
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('kmdist').value = calculatedDistance;
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried, but it's not in the post array.